# Check picture box location in if statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way I can use an if statement to evaluate whether an image is in a certain location?

For example something like:

```
If picturebox1.Location = (500,500) Then
   label1.Text = nothing
End if
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Try this:

```
If picturebox1.Location = new Point(500,500) Then
```